# Creating and accessing custom module's REST routes in Prestashop 1.7.5

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to create a custom controller in my Prestashop 1.7.5 module.

**I created a custom controller:**

```
# /var/www/html/modules/Profit/src/controller/ProductProfitController.php

namespace Profit\Controller;

use PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ProductProfitController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController {

    public function test() {
        return JsonResponse();
    }
}
```

**I loaded the class with my `composer.json` file:**

```
# /var/www/html/modules/Profit/composer.json

{
    "name": "company/profit",
    "description": "Moduł opłacalności",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Name",
            "email": "Email"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {            
            "Profit\\Controller\\": "src/controller/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "Profit.php",
            "src/"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": []
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "prepend-autoloader": false
    },
    "type": "prestashop-module",
    "author": "Name",
    "license": ""
}
```

**I added a route in my module's `routes` folder**

```
# /var/www/html/modules/Profit/config/routes.yml

update_price_cut:
    path: Profit/price-cut
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
      _controller: 'Profit\Controller\ProductProfitController::test'
```

**Yet I do not know how to access that route. I tried:**

```
localhost:8001/admin-dev/Profit/price-cut
localhost:8001/modules/Profit/price-cut
localhost:8001/modules/Profit/Profit/price-cut
localhost:8001/Profit/price-cut
```

None of these work. Every single one of them leads to a 404 error.

Is this the proper way of creating routes to your module's custom controller? How can I fix this?

**NOTE:** This controller is supposed to be a BackOffice controller. I want to use it to update products' details from the default PrestaShop product list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **$this->generateUrl('update_price_cut')** within admin controllers. It will generate a correct route to your controller. Or if you need it in a different place you can create own service and use it. More information you can find [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer didn't help me much, plus it doesn't mention the actual URL, for people stumbling on here through Google.

#### Setup

```php
# /config/routes.yml

my_route_name:
  path: /my_project/my_path # Leading / can be omitted
  methods: [GET]
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Me\MyProject\Admin\Controllers\MyController::indexAction' # This can point to any class and any public method.
```

```php
// my_project/admin/controllers/MyController.php

class MyController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController
{
    public function indexAction(): string 
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

So then I went down the same path of trying to figure out the URL and I finally ended up here.

#### The actual controller URL

The method `generateUrl`, mentioned in the other answer is not present in any of my admin controllers for some reason. I looked and discovered it's defined in a Symfony trait. It essentially does this:

```php
$this->container->get('router')->generate('my_route_name', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH);
```

Which finally returned the working URL:

```
/admin1/index.php/modules/my_project/my_path?_token=...
```

Hope this can help anyone else.